# The bibliography does not occupy all text width in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, margins

I am trying to modify the margins of the references page, but the bibliography does not stretch over all the width available for it. Instead, it occupies a width very similar to the one that would have been occupied before modifying the margins.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, xcolor={x11names}]{beamer}

\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{inmargin}
    \setbeamersize{text margin left=5mm, text margin right=5mm}
    \setbeamersize{sidebar width left=0.3\paperwidth, sidebar width right=0cm}

% Changing page commands

    % Set margins
    \newlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}
    \setlength{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}{5mm}
    \newlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}
    \setlength{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}{5mm}

    % Command to change margins for a page wide
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\framePageWide}{
        \def\Gm@lmargin{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}%
        \def\Gm@rmargin{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}%
        \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-\Gm@rmargin\relax
        \hsize\textwidth
        \columnwidth\textwidth
        \hoffset=\dimexpr-\beamer@leftsidebar+\Gm@lmargin-\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide\relax
    }
    \makeatother

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

{\framePageWide

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks=0.9]{Referencing}

\cite{dvzafic2014sensitivity}

\cite{saxena2014identification}

\cite{su2016estimating}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{alpha}


\bibliography{motasem_bib}

\end{frame}

}

\end{document}
```

Contents of `motasem_bib`

```
@article{saxena2014identification,
    title={Identification of multiple harmonic sources in power system using optimally placed voltage measurement devices},
    author={Saxena, D and Bhaumik, Sayak and Singh, SN},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Industrial Electronics},
    volume={61},
    number={5},
    pages={2483--2492},
    year={2014},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{su2016estimating,
    title={Estimating the voltage stability margin using PMU measurements},
    author={Su, Heng-Yi and Liu, Chih-Wen},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
    volume={31},
    number={4},
    pages={3221--3229},
    year={2016},
    publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{dvzafic2014sensitivity,
    title={A sensitivity approach to model local voltage controllers in distribution networks},
    author={D{\v{z}}afi{\'c}, Izudin and Jabr, Rabih A and Halilovic, Ema and Pal, Bikash C},
    journal={IEEE Transactions on Power Systems},
    volume={29},
    number={3},
    pages={1419--1428},
    year={2014},
    publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Comment: The problem is unrelated to the bibliography, you can reproduce it with a simple list: `{\framePageWide

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
\item long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}

}
`

Comment: @samcarter. I did not note that because I use two columns after adjusting the margins

Comment: You can compare `\textwidth` and `\linewidth`, `\linewidth` has not been updated (`\rule\textwidth{2mm}\par\rule\linewidth{2mm}` right after the `\newpage`)

Comment: Adding `\linewidth\textwidth` to `\framePageWide` seems to work. I do not remember the correct procedure for updating `\linewidth`, and `beamer` might be special in that regard)

Comment: is this the same as `\setlength{\linewidth}{\textwidth}`?

Comment: Probably, I just used that synax because that was already being used for `\columnwidth`. BTW: if you want to address someone who has commented, then use @username, then they will get notified.

Comment: @daleif Do you want to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter done

Comment: @daleif Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bibliographies are normally implemented as lists. These are build around `\linewidth`, a length that is updated internally, such that line width is smaller inside a normal list. By default `\linewidth` has the size of `\hsize`.

When you do

```
\hsize\textwidth
\columnwidth\textwidth
```

`\hsize` is set to `\textwidth`, so is `\columnwidth`. But `\linewidth` is never updated, so you get the same value for `\linewidth` as you got before using `\framePageWide`

If we take a look at the `geometry` package, its internal change layout macro ends with

```
\setlength{\hsize}{\columnwidth}
\setlength{\linewidth}{\hsize}
```

So changing your definition to

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\framePageWide}{
    \def\Gm@lmargin{\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide}%
    \def\Gm@rmargin{\widthTextMarginRightPageWide}%
    \textwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\Gm@lmargin-\Gm@rmargin\relax
    \hsize\textwidth
    \columnwidth\textwidth
    \linewidth\hsize   
    \hoffset=\dimexpr-\beamer@leftsidebar+\Gm@lmargin-\widthTextMarginLeftPageWide\relax
}
\makeatother
```

should do the trick